# Configuring Maven central along with client managed nexus

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, nexus

I am working on a project where I need to use maven central repository along with client managed nexus.
Want to download some libraries from maven nexus and some from client managed nexus. Could anyone please help me on how to set up setting.xml for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best is to use the nexus only and proxy central via the nexus....

Comment: Yes, this was 1 option. But I am using aws codeartifact as proxy. There is some issue in AWS codeartifact and because of that issue, codeartifact is unable to download few libraries from central. and that's why I am trying to use 2 separate repositories.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I set up upstream as maven public for my client specific nexus. So, if the libraries are not found in client specific repository, it will go to upstream and try to download in the nexus. Setting up upstream connection is very important here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `repositories` tag in the `pom.xml`, the location Maven needs to download remote artifacts from. We can do this in two ways - Check this https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo1</id>
      <name>Client Repo</name>
      <url>https://alltechtutorials.com</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo2</id>
      <name>your custom client repo</name>
      <url>https://bestjavatutorials.com</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I have tried setting up like this, but getting the below error:

`Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to Maven repository (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset `